# xcode shell script invocation error: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, shell

Used this tutorial to create my debug/release configurations.
Getting this error:

```
cp: “/Users/MyUserName/Projects/MyProjectName/Debug.plist”: No such file or directory
```

Problem is that i already have this file at this directory and even using in terminal :`"open /Users/MyUserName/Projects/MyProjectName/Debug.plist"`
opens it with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **answer** is [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20890). Just avoid curly quotes, when using your shell scripts.